# How to get rocktron talk box to sound like peter frampton?

Tags: guitar, guitar-effects, live-sound

I want my guitar to [sound like this](http://youtu.be/y7rFYbMhcG8?t=5m45s) though my  [rocktron banshee](http://www.rocktron.com/banshee-2.html). Sadly it doesnt sound *nearly* as clean.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without hearing your setup, this will be speculation, but one of the things you notice from Peter Frampton's setup is a very clean, undistorted guitar sound, with only a little gain/overdrive.

Are you using too much distortion? That's one of the mistakes people tend to make when using voice boxes.

The other thing that is useful is to cut a bunch of your bass out, and turn off any reverb.

Comment: ok. the gain needs to be dead zero. that makes it way quieter but cleaner. Now I just need to figure out his other effects. Whats in there other than reverb?

Comment: Chet - see my first sentence. On my setup I can get a very similar sound with just that. You need to give us more info about your setup.

Comment: All I have right now is a rocktron banshee 2 talk box with a guitar -- no effects. I took the gain all the way down and it sounds much closer. But he's got a very unique sound that I'm trying to match and I seems like he has some effects that I can't figure out off the top of my head.

Comment: If you want the list: http://www.uberproaudio.com/who-plays-what/745-peter-frampton-guitar-rig-gear-and-equipment

Comment: thats so cool. I didn't know this website existed

Comment: I'd you ever just want to know about guitarists kit, there are websites on every single one. Describing hardware, effects, software, process etc